# Плавное появление надежности пароля

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Привет. Скрипт проверяющий надежность пароля, вопрос такой: при добавлении каждого нового символа, блок появляется заново плавно (в блоке выходит уровень безопасности). Как сделать, чтобы только один раз показывало плавно каждый уровень безопасности?

```
<div id="bg">
     <p id="result"></p>
     <p id="bg_res"></p>    
</div>
```

===

```
 function check(pass) {
            var protect = 0;
            $("#bg").hide().fadeIn(500);
            if(pass.length < 8) {
                $("#bg_res").removeClass();
                $("#bg_res").addClass('red');
                return "Слабый";
            }

            //a,s,d,f
            var small = "([a-z]+)";
            if(pass.match(small)) {
                protect++;
            }

            //A,B,C,D
            var big = "([A-Z]+)";
            if(pass.match(big)) {
                protect++;
            }
            //1,2,3,4,5 ... 0
            var numb = "([0-9]+)";
            if(pass.match(numb)) {
                protect++;
            }
            //!@#$
            if(pass.match(/\W/)) {
                protect++;
            }

            if(protect == 2) {
                $("#bg_res").removeClass();
                $("#bg_res").addClass('yellow');
                return "Средний";
            }
            if(protect == 3) {
                $("#bg_res").removeClass();
                $("#bg_res").addClass('green');
                return "Хороший";
            }
            if(protect == 4) {
                $("#bg_res").removeClass();
                $("#bg_res").addClass('green_v');
                return "Высокий";
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если не особо вдаваясь в расчеты, то сделать можно [примерно так](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/o0t0vren/):

```
var checkPass = {
    regs : [/[a-z]+/,/[A-Z]+/,/[0-9]+/,/[\W]/],
    rating: function(str){
        var cnt = str.length > 8 ? 0 : -1;
        for(var i = 0; i < this.regs.length; i++){
            if(this.regs[i].test(str)) cnt++;
        }
        return this.styles[cnt];
    },
    styles:[
        {width: '20%', backgroundColor: '#F00'},
        {width: '40%', backgroundColor: '#FE4D01'},
        {width: '60%', backgroundColor: '#FF8000'},
        {width: '80%', backgroundColor: '#C4FC03'},
        {width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#00A400'}
    ]
};
$('#pass').on('input', function(){
    $('#progress div').finish().animate(checkPass.rating($(this).val()), 500);
});
```

Comment: @Deonis, очень понравился Ваш вариант, Спасибо) А вот только теперь нет слов (слабый, средний....), или может лучше в процентах показывать на цвете. Покажите пожалуйста.

Comment: @Alextrue, можно и [со словами][1]

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/o0t0vren/1/

Comment: @Deonis, Супер! Огромное спасибо!:)

Comment: @Deonis, не могу библиотеку найти, можете дать ссылку. Нашел но не работает.

Comment: @Alextrue, вы про [библиотеку jQuery][1] или про библиотеку имени Пушкина?

   [1]:http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: @Deonis, а какую именно скачать?)

Comment: @Alextrue, если нужно учитывать IE8 и ниже версий, то качайте 1.11.1, если на эти браузеры ставку не делаете, то 2.1.1. Качайте сжатые версии - compressed. Не думаю, что вам понадобиться что-то изменять в самой библиотеке руками.